# In Smalltalk, how to select both strings and integers from an array

Tags: string, select, integer, smalltalk, pharo

Using [Pharo](http://pharo.org/), I have a collection e.g.

```
array := #('up' '4' 'b').
```

and I'd like to use `select:` to create a collection that only includes the numbers, provided they're smaller than 20, and a specific string - in this case, 'up' and '4'

I tried:

```
array select: [:each | (each='up') | (each asInteger < 50)].
```

This leads to a `MessageNotUnderstood` because `receiver of "<" is nil`.

I figured I'd have to create a local variable `x:= each asInteger`, but just couldn't work it out.

Comment: Are you trying to use the second vertical bar | as an 'or' operator? That's not Smalltalk.

Comment: @PaulRichter: sure it is. Inspect `true | false` or `true & false` in a workspace to see that it works. It's just more common to use `or:` and `and:` - and for good reason, because while the former two are called "evaluating disjunctions/conjunctions", the latter two are "non-evaluating disjunctions/conjunctions". As I said in my answer, the former two always evaluate the second condition, the latter only if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a `MessageNotUnderstood` because your code is trying to test whether `'b' asInteger` (which is `nil`, because `b` isn't an integer) is `< 20` (or `< 50`; you have different numbers in your text and your code). So all you need to do is test whether each array item is a number before you treat it as such.

This should work in a Pharo workspace:

```
| array |
array := #('up' '4' 'b' '22').
^array select: [ :each | each = 'up'
    or: [ each isAllDigits and: [ each asInteger < 20 ] ] ]
```

Inspecting the result of this gives `#('up' '4')` as expected.

Note that I'm checking whether each string is "made up of all digits", and only doing the comparison if that is the case. Also note that I'm using `or:` and `and:`, which only evaluate the block argument if required, while `|` and `&` evaluate both sides regardless.

You could also create a local variable, as you said you tried, but it would look a little clunkier (and I wouldn't call the variable `x`... unless it's an x-coordinate):

```
| array |
array := #('up' '4' 'b' '22').
^array select: [ :each |
    each = 'up' or: [
        | integerOrNil |
        integerOrNil := each asInteger.
        integerOrNil notNil and: [ integerOrNil < 20 ] ] ]
```

Comment: The first snippet would work a bit better, because '1foo' asInteger would answer 1 and ignore trailing non digits... I don't know if it's a good thing, but that's how it is.

Comment: @aka.nice: Yep, agreed; the first example is the one I'd recommend. I only provided the second example because the OP said that he/she had tried it that way and didn't get it to work, i.e. I wanted to show how a temporary variable inside a block would work (I assume that's what the problem was).

Answer (score 3):

Using `select:` you can only access one element of the array at a time. From your code I see you want to access two elements of the array at the same time. You could use in this case `pairsDo:`. For example the code below puts in an array all numbers that are preceded by the string 'up'.

```
numbers := OrderedCollection new.
#('up' '5' 'b') pairsDo: [ :first :second |
    ((first = 'up') and: [ second asInteger notNil ])
        ifTrue: [ numbers add: second asInteger ] ]
```

You could then use `select:` to only get those numbers less than 20:

```
numbers select: [:each| each < 20].
```

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because second statement of comparison is being executed always: the message | in pharo (and any smalltalk) does not work as the homonym C operator, instead it is executed always, regardless the result of the first part of the statement (same happens with &, btw).

For having similar results you seem to pretend (execute the or clause just if first clause is true), we use the messages **or:** and **and:**

You can do:

```
array select: [ :each | 
    each = 'up'
    or: [ each = '4' 
    or: [ each isAllDigits and: [ each asInteger < 20 ] ] ] ]
```

Notice the nesting for calling the #or: statements and the fact I first check if the number can be converted to a number. If I do not do it like that, I will get **nil** when I try to convert a string to a number, because parsing (conversion) of a string into a number failed (and then the select will fail).

Another possible way to do it is:

```
array select: [ :each | 
    each = 'up'
    or: [ each = '4' 
    or: [ each asInteger notNil and: [ each asInteger < 20 ] ] ] ]
```

But I recommend the first one (using the fail of the parser a a way to determine if a string contains a number can be easily be considered an exploit :)

Finally, If you have to select more than one or two "constant" string, you can do something like:

```
constants := #('up' '4').
array select: [ :each | 
    (constants includes: each)
    or: [ each asInteger notNil and: [ each asInteger < 20 ] ] ]
```

which is probably a more clean implementation.